# Android RecyclerView как в Badoo

Tags: android, recyclerview, layoutmanager

Как можно реализовать список подобный списку "люди рядом" в Badoo?
Какой LayoutManager менеджер использовать?

[image: пример]

Comment: мне кажется, это 3 обычных `LinearLayout` (или `TableLayout`), в среднем из которых сделан отступ

Answer (score 4):

Нашел способ без сторонних библиотек. Используем StaggeredGridLayoutManager и ItemDecoration.

```
public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int space;

    public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
        this.space = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

        if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) == 1) {
            outRect.top = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.base_90) - space;
        } else {
            outRect.top = space;
        }
        outRect.bottom = space;
    }
}

RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.base_16)));
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего здесь использован компонент `StaggeredGridView`. Есть пара хороших либ: [раз](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid), [два](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView)